# Проблема парсинга на Python, auto.ru

Tags: python, парсер

Собственно программирование изучать начал, сравнительно недавно. Но вроде понемногу добрался до парсинга. Посмотрел, как это делал Олег Молчанов, и решил попробовать самостоятельно спарсить auto.ru (вывести список объявлений, цену и так далее), сугубо, в образовательных целях. И при получении списка страниц, я столкнулся с проблемой:
К примеру на сайте, когда захожу через браузер, в нижней части написано 1, 2, 3 ...50 страниц (то есть я хочу получить значение 50), но когда я осуществляю запрос с помощью requests.get(), вижу, что их там не 50 страниц, а уже 37. Это какая-то защита сайта и как это вообще можно решить? Пробовал скачивать вручную страницу, все значения корректны. Попробовал скачивать страницу в python c помощью urlopen и сохранять в файл для дальнейшей манипуляции в локальном режиме, такая же история

Comment: Может быть python получает данные не для того региона, не для тех фильтров и т.п. Помните что когда Вы получаете данные с помощью requests.get(), у Вас получается совершенно голый браузер, без куков и реккомендаций, как будто бы вы зашли на сайт впервые.

Comment: кажется вы правы, сейчас попробовал через другой браузер открыть и понял, что меняется радиус поиска